# use command:ionic cordova build android --prod --release;failed and The ionic3 app starts too long and fails

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I hava two question:

1. Use the command：`ionic cordova build android --prod --release`. Failed
   like this:

[image: f]

build failed.

2. The ionic3 app starts too long and fails

[image: s]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get better answers for your questions

Answer (score 0):

the answer for second question is,
The APK that you installed is not the output of

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

or any build command

its the output of

```
ionic cordova run android -l -c
```

(run APK works when the server is 'on' from the computer).